# If $a^2+a$ lies in the center of $R$ a ring, then $R$ is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $a^2+a$ lies in the center of $R$ for any $a\in R$ then using $(a+b)^2+(a+b)$ I get that $ab+ba$ is also in the center of $R$,then $ab^2=b^2a$ but I don´t know how to porve that $ab=ba$.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean to say "$a^2+a$ lies in the center of $R$ for any $a\in R$"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the fact that $b^2 + b$ is in the center, you have $a(b^2 + b) = (b^2 + b)a$. This should be enough to finish.